# Term confusion about volume scattering

Tags: physically-based, volume-rendering, theory, volumetric-scattering, scattering

We have two different terms, for example, let's talk about scattering only.

- Scattering coefficient
- Scattering cross-section

These two terms are supposed to have different physical meaning. I read it from the [PBR-book - Chapter 11](https://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/Volume_Scattering/Volume_Scattering_Processes#Absorption) :

> Absorption is described by the medium’s absorption cross section, , which is the probability density that light is absorbed per unit distance traveled in the medium.

But the wikipedia told me:

> The SI unit of attenuation coefficient is the reciprocal metre (m−1). [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient)

And this:

> This is also commonly expressed as: $\sigma = \alpha /n$, where $\alpha$ is the absorption coefficient, $n$ is the atomic number density [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_cross_section)

So I suppose **xxx cross-section** and **xxx coefficient** should be different, therefore should have different unit. But it seems that, in rendering, these two terms are interchangeable? Like in mitsuba and PBRT we will set **$\sigma$** instead of $\mu$, although they are just names. In rendering, the so-called **cross-section** (in PBR-book) has the same unit as **xxx coefficient** ($m^{-1}$), but they should be distinguished by $N$, which should have the unit of $m^{-3}$.

My confusion is what exactly are we setting in those renderers, and in theory, which term is the correct term to use? And, whether there is anything more work I should do, to convert the *unitless* distance in those renderers to be a physical value (Like multiply $\sigma_x$ by N)?

Comment: Normally publications refer to the "scattering coefficient" is the "out scattering coefficient" which is the probability of a photon, being out scattered. Where as the "scattering cross-section" is usually computed as part of the "absorption cross-section". Which is a measure of how likely a photon is going to absorbed as it travels through a medium. They are related but separate concepts. Most models use a unitless combination of the two called the scattering coefficient. But alone they do have units. If the two are not separated out internally then combining them seems like a good approach.

Comment: @pmw1234 Thanks for the comment. I just found that they might be separated in other related fields lile optics, but not in CG. Since I wish my rendering to correspond well with realistic data, I don't want any misunderstanding in the parameter settings in the renderer.